# VxWorks BSP selection/modification

Tags: vxworks

I have a  board "ARIES SBC with Intel E3845 Bay Trail Processor". I want to run VxWorks 6.9 on it .
 From the provided  BSPs I seleceted  these BSPs which look closer to our Board.

1. Itl_atom
2. itl_core2_64

I tried with both of these BSPs and run in the given board but not succeeded.

I tried with Grub and default vxworks boatloader but  nothing appears on serial console.

Now I am confused. Either I have selected correct BSP. or I have to modify these BSPs according to my Board.
which parameters should we change in config.h file.

How should I proceed?

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks,

Junaid

Comment: You should look for below changes, see ram configuration does it match your board specification, check flash size modify according to your requirement. Check console settings, romInit.s is good start? Are there led which in board, you can debug using LED at what point you have reached.  Check BSP developer guide, it can provide your debug points what to look for.

Comment: Thanks.I have made bootable flash as per target.ref . On starting  I get the following output .v1.6+ ( 10- 12 lines of +++ ) then it hangs and does not display the vxworks boot prompt Now on my board I have the LEDs  on the board but it can only be used by the   provided BSPs ( Windows and linux ).I dont have the address of leds so i cannot  use it in baremetal fashion. Also the board user manual does not provide me the system memory map addresses.Can i write some assembly code ( e.g. printf ) in rominit.s which i can see on VGA  display for debugging. or any other tip which you can provide.

Comment: Things to check, 1. Have you configured RAM_HIGH_ADRS properly? 2. Ensure image is in right placed in RAM and ROM use nm tool to dump infomration from your binary and see segments. 3. Refer to this note: http://www.vxdev.com/down/appnote/appnote237.pdf 4. U cannot  displayign anything in VGA as your UART wouldn't  have been initialized, so best bet would be LED. If uart is initialized, it would be very easy to dump information.